# Unable to get ellipsis for Multiline Paragraph

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a block of texts where I want to get Ellipsis for 4/5 lines
but if I use

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

in a paragraph tag, I get the ellipsis for only one single line
I want my paragraph to look like this
[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is super easy to do because of the `line-clamp` property in CSS.
Just use this:

```css
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
line-clamp: 5; /* you can keep it any thing*/
white-space: nowrap;
```

So, what the `line-clamp` will do is it will let the paragraph go to particular number of lines before it adds the ellipsis.
More information here: [css-tricks line-clamp](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/)

the answer to this problem on the website is this:

```css
.line-clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p class="line-clamp">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Comment: I recommend adding "height: 3lh;" which will keep partial line overflows.